# Obfuscating email addresses displayed by Views?

Tags: views, users, emails

I'm working on a View that displays a user's email field as a mailto. Given this is a recipe for spam, I'm wanting some way of obfuscating it.

I thought I'd go with [Invisimail](http://drupal.org/project/invisimail), but it (and seemingly ever other similar project) relies on a text filter. Given that the User email field doesn't use input formats, this makes it useless for my particular application.

I suppose I could create a separate email field, but I'd really like to not have to.

In short -- **How do I obfuscate a user email field displayed via Views?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spamspan](http://drupal.org/project/spamspan) module will help you. It can obfuscate email addresses from email fields along with emails provided inline in text.

For email field - chooses Spamspan formatter in display settings.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have the same problem (listing users' email address in a view), however I'm not using a custom email field but just the existing user's account email field. I can't find any display settings for the account email field. Can I apply Spamspan to this email field?

Comment: Hi Ben, you can try.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have tried without success.

Answer (score 1):

To obfuscate the default users email field in a view you need to combine answers from Eugene and Eva.

- install [spamspan](http://drupal.org/project/spamspan) module
- use the users email field in a view
- copy the file views-view-field.tpl.php from [path_to_modules]/views/theme folder to your theme folder
- change file name from views-view-field.tpl.php to views-view-field--mail.tpl.php
- replace the default output in that file for the code snippet from Eva
- clear theme cache

Answer (score -1):

We use custom tpl.php file for the user account email field. In this field we have the following code:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('spamspan')) {
  print spamspan($output);
} else {
  print $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: is this `<?php` tag really there, just before this call? If no, why put it here?